# knockout not auto updated computed value

Tags: knockout.js

function for Violation:

```
function Violation(violCd, desc, amt) {
        this.violCd = ko.observable(violCd);
        this.desc = ko.observable(desc);
        this.amtToPay = ko.observable(amt);
    }
```

View Model:

```
 self.violations = ko.observableArray([]);

 self.addViol = function () {
      alert('adding');
      self.violations.push(new Violation({ violCd: "28-0000", desc: "DUI OR SOMETHING",
     amtToPay: "300" }));
}
self.total = ko.computed(function () {
      alert(total);
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < self.violations.length; i++) {
           total += self.violations[i].amtToPay;
      }
      return total;
});
```

The html is:

```
<input data-bind="value: total()" />
```

I need the total to auto update as soon as a violation is added.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So the main issue is to do with `self.violations`. This needs to be declared as an `observablearray` so that if items are added then knockout knows that they have been added and can update the computed total.

```
self.violations = ko.observableArray();
```

Then when ever you access the array to get the contents you will need to use `self.violations()` so your computed function should be:

```
self.total = ko.computed(function () {
      alert(total);
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < self.violations().length; i++) {
           total += self.violations()[i].amtToPay;
      }
      return total;
});
```

One other issue is that amtToPay is set as a string so in javascript `0 + "300" = "0300"`. It should be set as an int or float:

```
self.violations.push(new Violation({ violCd: "28-0000", desc: "DUI OR SOMETHING",
     amtToPay: 300 }));
```

You could possibly have to also make the properties in `Violation` as observable as well if it's possible to just modify the value of a property without modifying the array.

eg:

```
self.violations()[0].amtToPay = 300;
```

That change won't be noticed by knockout so you would need to declare amtToPay as an observable:

```
self.amtToPay = ko.observable();
```

Then to access the value you would need to use `self.violations[i]().amtToPay()`.

If it's input from the user then it would be a string so you would need to convert it to an int or float using [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) or [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp).

Comment: I have declared self.violations as an observable array and declared the properties in violations as observable - sorry I should have put that code. So that's why I can't figure out why it is not working.             self.violations = ko.observableArray([]); I will edit my previous post to put in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using this:

```
        self.violations = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.addViol = function () {

            self.violations.push(new violation({ violCd: "28-0000", desc: "DUI OR SOMETHING", amt: "300" }));
            self.violations.valueHasMutated();

        }
        self.total = ko.computed(function () {
            var total = 0;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.violations(), function (violation) {
                var value = parseFloat(violation.amt());
                if (!isNaN(value)) {
                    total += value;
                }
            });
            return total.toFixed(2);
        });
```

Now it seems to notice a change.